# is it possible to convert date format from encrypted date string in MSSQL

Tags: sql, date, numeric

I want to return date from a table.

The value of the startDate format is : 1588244766682

When I execute the query :

select CAST(startDate AS DATE) , CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  from arch_report;

I got an error : 
 Explicit conversion from data type numeric to date is not allowed.

Is it possible to convert this type of date to date type?
I may miss some parts.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) to calculate the date.

We'll divide by 1000 (since your startDate value is in milliseconds) to get the number of seconds since the unix epoch.

```
declare @startTime bigint;
set @startTime = 1588244766682;
SELECT DATEADD(second, @startTime/1000, '1970-01-01') AS start_time;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however, FROM_UNIXTIME seems not working in MSSQL server. 
I am search more information compare FROM_UNIXTIME.
Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I was assuming you were using MySQL, rather than SQL Server. I've updated my answer1

Comment: Thank you so much I could get the result correctly.

Comment: Glad to be of help!